# How to synchronize access to a global variable with very frequent reads / very rare writes?

Tags: c++, c, windows, multithreading, thread-safety

I’m working on debug logging infrastructure for a server application. Each logging point in source code specifies its level (CRITICAL, ERROR, etc.) among other parameters.
So in source code logging point looks as:

```
DBG_LOG_HIGH( … )
```

which is a macro that expands to

```
if ( CURRENT_DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL >= DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL_HIGH ) {
   // prepare and emit log record
}
```

where `DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL_HIGH` is a predefined constant (let’s say 2) and `CURRENT_DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL` is some expression that evaluates to the current debug logging level set by the user.
The simplest approach would be to define `CURRENT_DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL` as:

```
extern int g_current_debug_log_level;
#define CURRENT_DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL (g_current_debug_log_level)
```

I would like to allow user to change the current debug logging level during the application execution and its okay for the change to take a few seconds to take effect. The application is multi-threaded and changes to `g_current_debug_log_level` can be easily serialized (for instance by `CRITICAL_SECTION`) but in order not to impact performance expression `( CURRENT_DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL >= DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL_HIGH )` should execute as fast as possible so I would like to avoid using any thread synchronization mechanism there.

So my questions are:

1. Can the absence of synchronization in `g_current_debug_log_level` reads cause incorrect value to be read? While it should not affect application correctness because user could have set the current debug logging level to the incorrect value anyway it might affect the application performance because it might cause it to emit very high volume of debug log for uncontrollable period of time.
2. Will my solution guarantee that change in the current debug logging level will reach all the threads after the acceptable amount of time (let’s say a few seconds)? Ideally I would like level change operation to be synchronous so that when user receives acknowledgement on level change operation she can count on subsequent log to be emitted according the new level.

I would also greatly appreciate any suggestions for alternative implementations that satisfies the above requirements (minimal performance impact for level comparison and synchronous level change with no more than a few seconds latency).

Comment: If the variable is in memory shared between threads, any change will be picked up immediately by other threads. You need to protect writes only if they can happen from different threads simultaneously. If multiple threads change it simultaneously, the worst that can happen is that you will end up with the old value. It cannot be that "half" of the int will be written to ram or such. PS there are logging libraries available.

Comment: Assuming the value is properly aligned, you can just perform direct reads and writes. Direct reads and writes of aligned register-sized data are already atomic on Windows. You may want to mark the variable `volatile` so that the compiler will not optimize it out of loops. (e.g. `while (CURRENT_DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL < DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL_HIGH) { ... }` may be optimized to `if (CURRENT_DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL < DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL_HIGH) while (true) { ... }` because the compiler "knows" that `g_current_debug_log_level` is not modified in the loop.

Comment: @Raymond Chen: The tricky thing is that I'm actually ok with `CURRENT_DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL` read being optimized out of very tight loops because as I said it changes rarely and its semantics is such that if some tight loop uses the same level for all its iterations even though it became stale in the middle it's ok. The only requirement is that new level will reach all the threads in short period of time and I could acknowledge the change to the outside caller.

Comment: @Raymond Chen: Also as I commented below `volatile` will cause acquire memory fence on each level check and I expect performance to suffer.

Comment: If you are not concerned about the compiler optimizing out redundant reads, then just do direct reads and writes. The updated value will reach all CPUs eventually. (Though I think worrying about acquire fences is a bit of a premature optimzation. It is unlikely to be a performance bottleneck.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing that requires that a write made on one thread on one core will ever become visible to another thread reading on another core, without providing some sort of fence to create a 'happens before' edge between the write and the read.

So to be strictly correct, you would need to insert the appropriate memory fence / barrier instructions after the write to the log level, and before each read. Fence operations aren't cheap, but they are cheaper than a full blown mutex.

In practice though, given a concurrent application that is using locking elsewhere, and the given fact that your program will continue to operate more or less correctly if the write does not become visible, it is likely that the write will become visible incidentally due to other fencing operations within a short timescale and meet your requirements. So you can probably get away with just writing it and skipping the fences.

But using proper fencing to enforce the happens before edge is really the correct answer. FWIW, C++11 provides an explicit memory model which defines the semantics and exposes these sorts of fencing operations at the language level. But as far as I know no compiler yet implements the new memory model. So for C/C++ you need use lock from a library or explicit fencing.

Comment: Wasn't `std::memory_order_consume` introduced in C++11 specifically to deal with "very frequent reads/very rare writes" situation? That's what the opening of [n2664](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2664.htm) seems to imply.

Comment: As Jason S notes above, my answer is also only correct if you are using reads/writes for one variable of atomic size. Otherwise, you must use a mutex to avoid seeing partial updates.

Comment: Cubbi - Yes, I mentioned at the end that C++11 added support for describing these sorts of dependency edges within the language, which I think will be great. I didn't want to go into too much detail though because I'm not an expert on them, and it is unlikely that they could be used right now anyway.

Comment: @Cubbi: I'm using VC++ 2008 and plan to switch to VC++ 2010 soon but AFAIK none of them implements thread related part of C++11 so the question is: is there anything Windows provides that accomplishes the same goal although platform dependent?

Comment: @Sergey Kleyman On second thought, unless there's another shared value to access, no fencing is necessary at all, just the atomicity. They said they've implemented <atomic> [in Visual Studio 2011](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293(v=vs.110).aspx), I wonder how.

Comment: @Cubbi: So if I understand you correctly you're saying to leave it as it's and hope for the best :) 
I don't want to over engineer this thing either if the simplest approach will work but on the other hand I don't want the naive solution to crumble on me because of some weird thread timing, etc.
I just cannot shake off the feeling that I should ensure "... become visible ... within a short timescale" guarantee in code.

Comment: Maybe by making `CURRENT_DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL` into a function that returns cached `g_current_debug_log_level` most of the time but every so often (every 1 second for instance) ensuring that it has the latest `g_current_debug_log_level`. Not sure how to do it though without making `CURRENT_DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL` slow all the time :(

Comment: @SergeyKleyman: I'm guessing you meant acm since you quoted me... Yes. Especially if you are on x86 you can probably get away with it. However, you are gambling. Note also that someone suggested volatile implies a fence: not true. However, you still may need volatile to prevent the optimizer from being overly aggressive. Also remember that an uncontended mutex is very fast. My real advice: start with a mutex, because you know it is correct. Write torture tests. Profile. If it is too slow, try atomics. Still to slow? Try explicit fences. Still to slow? Take the eventually consistent gamble.

Comment: Windows is x86 and x86 does not need fencing. All writes invalidate the corresponding cache lines on all other cpus/cores; this behavior is part of the ISA.

Comment: @R Windows runs on processors other than x86. You're probably running such a version right now.

Comment: @acm: IIRC, MSVC adds fences to `volatile`. Raymond should have mentioned it's a MS-ism, though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on Windows and Windows only runs on x86 (which is mostly-true for now but may change...), and assuming only one thread ever writes to the variable, you can get away without doing any synchronization whatsoever.

To be "correct", you should be using a reader-writer lock of some form.

Comment: That's true for only one variable of atomic size. A single thread could change two values [A1,B1] to [A2,B2], and depending on memory barriers + caching + whatnot, the logging thread might pick up [A1,B2] or [A2,B1] as well as the normal pairs [A1,B1] or [A2,B2].

Comment: Indeed, I was assuming a single variable, at most 32-bit, and **properly aligned**. This last assumption could be the most misguided assumption of mine considering how Windows programmers seem to love `#pragma pack` so much...

Comment: @Jason S: Let me clarify - there's no logging thread - all the threads do their own logging. For simplicity sake let's assume that the only shared data relevant to the question is "current debug log level" which is 32-bit int.

Comment: In that case I think my answer applies, as long as only one thread is able to change the logging level. Even if multiple threads can change it, you're probably still fine as long as you don't care about strict ordering of the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Given your current implementation, I suggest you take a look at atomic operations. If this is intended for Windows only, look at [Interlocked Variable Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684122(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Using `atomic` (C++11) or `Interlocked` (Windows) would cause memory acquire fence on each level comparison and I would like to avoid that if possible for performance reasons. Essentially I would like to optimize for frequent reads on the expense of very rare writes which might "push" the value "closer" to reads.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the new Slim Reader/Writer locks available on Vista and 7. They should do what you want with as little overhead as possible:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa904937(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm afraid that Slim Reader/Writer lock is an overkill to protect just one integer. Slim Reader/Writer lock internal machinery will have much higher performance overhead than Interlocked functions for instance.

Answer (score 0):

On x86 and x64 volatile will impose very few direct costs.  There may be some indirect costs related to forcing re-fetch of unrelated variables (accesses to volatile variables are treated as compiler-level memory fences for all other 'address taken' variables). Think of a volatile variable as like a function call in that the compiler will lose information about the state of memory across the call.

On Itanium, volatile has some cost but it's not too bad.  On ARM, the MSVC compiler defaults to not providing barriers (and not providing ordering) for volatile.

One important thing is that there should be at least one access to this log level variable in your program, otherwise it might be turned into a constant and optimized out.  This could be a problem if you were intending to set the variable through no mechanism other than the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Define ordinal variable visible in the scope and update it as appropriate (when the log level changes)
If the data is correctly aligned (i.e. default one), then you don't need anything special except declaring your current log variable a "volatile". This would work for LONG size (32 bit ordinal).
So your solution would be:

```
extern volatile long g_globalLogLevel;
```

No need for external synchronization (i.e. RWlock/CriticalSection/Spin etc)